# Is there a good, online tutorial for learning intermediate-to-advanced Bash programmable completion?

Tags: bash, programmable-completion

My current skill level with programmable completion is pretty basic — about at "`complete -d cd`".  I'd like to significantly increase my knowledge (and use) of completion to increase my CLI productivity, but I'm having trouble finding an online resource which has much substance.  The vast majority of what I'm able to dig up via Google boils down to either "press [tab] twice" or "`apt-get bash_completion`"… and the few remaining sites simply offer large, complex completion scripts for use with specific programs (e.g. `svn`).

Where can I go to learn more?

Answer (score 2):

Doing some Googling, the best example I can find is this article: [An introduction to bash completion](http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/316)

I also find the archived [mailing list](http://www.mail-archive.com/bash-completion-devel@lists.alioth.debian.org/info.html) where you can ask for help if you have specific questions.

If I find anything more I'll edit this answer to add it in.

Comment: That's actually the very article that inspired the `apt-get` quip above. :-) I hadn't found that list, though. I'll have to check it out.

Answer (score 0):

This may not work, but have you tried contacting the maintainers of the completion scripts? Ask them on what resources they would recomend.